# Heroku- Set environment variable during scheduled task

Tags: ruby, heroku, sinatra

I'm trying to create a scheduled task on heroku that will set an environment variable for the application. How would I set this environment variable? Is there a way to invoke heroku config:add from within a scheduled task? (Ruby based application.)

Solved it:

require 'heroku-api'

heroku.put_config_vars(APP, KEY => 'value')

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to use the heroku.rb gem (https://github.com/heroku/heroku.rb) and invoke that from your task to set the variable.